# Postgres: foreign key constraint for components of a composite type?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint, composite-types

In Postgres, is it possible to set up a foreign key contraint involving components of a composite type, in a situation like the following one?

Suppose I have

```
CREATE TABLE main (
    -- a and b are separate fields
    a INTEGER,
    b INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (a,b)
);
CREATE TYPE abtype AS (
    a INTEGER,
    b INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE sub (
    -- a and b are components of a composite type
    ab abtype,
    PRIMARY KEY (ab)
);
```

How do I set up a foreign key constraint specifying that `sub.ab` references `main.(a,b)`?

The following attempts are all syntactically wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE sub ADD CONSTRAINT sub_ab_fkey FOREIGN KEY
... (ab) REFERENCES main(a,b);
... (ab) REFERENCES main((a,b));   
... (ab) REFERENCES main((a,b)::abtype);
... (ab) REFERENCES main(a,b)::abtype;
... ((ab).a,(ab).b) REFERENCES main(a,b);
... (ab.a,ab.b) REFERENCES main(a,b);
```

Comment: Index in 1st table consists from 2 fields, whereas in 2nd table from 1 field. None tricks in constraint expression can help. You must alter one of PKs (or create additional index for referencing).

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the clarification. I already suspected that I'm asking too much. The problem is that `main` is a long existing table where any change would break too much, whereas the composite type is the more convenient approach in newer tables.

Comment: I have tested a little... it seems that user-defined type is more complex than simple fields "concatenation, and its components needs additional function(s) for to assign/access them.

Comment: Maybe you cannot alter main PK, but maybe you could add a new composite column and use it a as reference for the other FK.

Comment: @McNets Good idea, thanks.

Comment: Don't use composite types like this. There is some sound reasoning behind the first normal form in relational databases.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What do you mean by 'like this'? The situation here is that `a` and `b` most of the time occur together, that the pair `(a,b)` is rather a type of its own and most queries and functions operate on the tuple instead of the components. I see no conflict between relational databases and user-defined types. In a perfect world, I would rewrite table main and all legacy code to use the type `ab`, but practically, this is not feasible.

Comment: If the two components were always together and the database never had to treat them individually, you would be right. But as it is, that is not the case, you you had better avoid this composite type. There is no advantage I can imagine over having the values in separate columns.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Well, the advantage is of a practical kind: the tuple is a really a triple, and there are many functions for computing with the triples. On the other hand, I don't yet see the disadvantage of having two views on the triple, except that it costs space to have another column for 1.5 billion records and another index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in comments, you could add a new composite column in `main` table:

```
CREATE TYPE abtype AS (
    a INTEGER,
    b INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE main (
    -- a and b are separate fields
    a INTEGER,
    b INTEGER,
    ab abtype generated always as ((a,b)) stored,
    PRIMARY KEY (a,b)
);

CREATE TABLE sub (
    -- a and b are components of a composite type
    ab abtype,
    PRIMARY KEY (ab)
);
```

And set a unique index:

```
create unique index on main (ab);
```

Now you can reference your FK to this column:

```
ALTER TABLE sub ADD CONSTRAINT sub_ab_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ab) references main(ab);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=74cb4ac2a4c032482d662891e5fcbc42)*